# check for isomorphic strings using a single map in javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Two words are called isomorphic if the letters in one word can be remapped to get the second word. Remapping a letter means replacing all occurrences of it with another letter while the ordering of the letters remains unchanged. No two letters may map to the same letter, but a letter may map to itself.

```
Example: 
('ABC','XYZ') //true
('ABCCBA','XYZZYX') //true
('ABCABC','XYXXYX') //false
```

My code uses two hashmap. Is there a way to do it using a single hashmap?

Code using two maps:

```
 function isomorphic(str1, str2){
        if(str1.length !== str2.length) return false;
        var map1={}, map2={};

        for (var i=0; i< str1.length;i++) {
            if (typeof map1[str1[i]] == "undefined" && typeof map2[str2[i]] == "undefined"){
                map1[str1[i]] = str2[i];
                map2[str2[i]] = str1[i];
            }
            else{
                if(map1[str1[i]] !== str2[i] && map2[str2[i]] !== str1[i]){
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Why doesn't this question belong on this site?

Comment: @eykanal Please stop voting to close because it belongs on Code Review. *"Belongs on Code Review"* is not a valid close reason. One should close as *"Too broad"*.

Comment: Hi, I got the answer for you, just tell me how to send it and i'll do it

Comment: `function isomorphic(str1, str2){
        if(str1.length !== str2.length) return false;
  var map = {};
  var i;
  var len = str1.length;

        for (i=0; i< len; i++) {
            if (!map[str1[i]]){
    map[str1[i]] = str2[i];
            }
            else{
    if(map[str1[i]] !== str2[i]){
     return false;
    }
    for(prop in map){
     if((map[prop] === str2[i]) && (str1[i] !== prop)){
      return false;
     }
    }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }`

Comment: @EthanBierlein - I disagree. There are two questions to ask when closing as "belongs on another site", (1) is it appropriate here, and (2) is it appropriate on the destination site. For this question, the answers are No (this is not a coding question, it's asking for better approaches to an existing solution) and Yes, respectively.  I think this is entirely appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work

```
function isomorphic(str1, str2) {
    if (str1.length !== str2.length) {
        return false;
    }
    var map = {};
    for(var i = 0; i < str1.length; i++) {
        var a = str1[i]; 
        var b = str2[i];
        if (typeof map[a] === "undefined") {
            map[a] = b;

        // check for error in first tuple ("ABB", "XYZ")
        } else if (map[a] !== b) {
            return false;
        }

        // check for error in second tuple ("ABC", "XYY")
        for (var key in map) {
            if (key !== a && b === map[key]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

isomorphic("ABC", "XYZ"); //true
isomorphic("ABCCBA", "XYZZYX"); //true
isomorphic("ABCABC", "XYXXYX"); // false
```

Comment: you are going through the whole map for no reason, just check the key

Comment: No, it does not work. You have to check if the value already exists, but with a different key

Comment: my bad, you're right